# Scrollable view

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout

I'm trying to display information contained on a json with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MarkerActivity">        
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Status" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview"
        android:layout_width="282dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mytextview"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mappin" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
    <ScrollView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
            android:text="Comments"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Comments" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jsonData1"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="83dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="STATS"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jsonData2"
            android:layout_width="157dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="COMMENTS"

android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need a scrollable view, due the fact that my json file could contain many entries and could fill all the space on the display.
With this code my program crash. Any idea how to solve it? I tried in many ways but always the same situation

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` needs to have one **child**, so wrap your `3 TextViews` in a `LinearLayout` layout and set it's height to `wrap_content`

```
ScrollView=>LinearLayout=>Textviews
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView can have only one child but you put 3 child in scrollView. thats why your app is crash.

You need to put all child (all three textView) in one ViewGroup. then your app will run correctly. here you can see

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MarkerActivity">        
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Small"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
            android:text="+" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Status" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytextview"
            android:layout_width="282dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mytextview"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mappin" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="9dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
        <ScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Comments" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/jsonData1"
                android:layout_width="155dp"
                android:layout_height="83dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="STATS"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/jsonData2"
                android:layout_width="157dp"
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="COMMENTS"
                android:textSize="16sp"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
                 />
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In this way it overlap all the elements and there is no possibility to scroll anything: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tuahQ0FtHHmtg39BuoNNOFkoVe8xvK3T/view?usp=sharing